# How to add a background color to active bootstrap 4 navbar item

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a background color to active bootstrap 4 navbar item [here](https://govtexam.justinechacko.in). It applied partially. How to apply to full height?
I used css like,

```
.active {
   background:rgba(165, 168, 168, 0.329);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, what do you mean by partially?? and what do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

The space is actually the **nav**'s element padding. One solution would be to eliminate the top and bottom padding. You can do this using [Boostrap's spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/) method by adding "**px-3 py-0**" classes to the **nav** element.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger fixed-top px-3 py-0"></nav>
```

You can set px from 1 to 5.

Also if you need the same height for the nav you can add some extra pixels for the height:

```
nav {
   height: 50px;
}

nav li a {
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 35px;
}
```

Also the height of the **a** should be increased in order to match the **nav**'s height. The **line-height** property should be adapted to center the text.

Comment: works partially, when adding `py-1` it goes to old state

Comment: Yes. you need to use py-0 to elminate the padding on y axe. If you need more height you need to add height for the "nav" element using css

Comment: Also if you increase the height of the nav you need to increase also the height of the a element with the same size. I will update my answer.

Comment: Worked flawlessly!

Comment: @JustineChacko, Great!

Comment: need a change `nav: {
   height: 50px;
}` to `nav {
   height: 50px;
}`?

Comment: Yes. My bad. Thank you

Comment: Can you please review my site. In responsive mode navbar have some problem in drop down box.

Comment: I see. It happend also before? Or only after you added the changes?

Comment: after adding `nav {
   height: 50px;
}

nav li a {
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 35px;
}`

Comment: From what I see the background-color of the ul element is missing. I don't understand how to height changing can affect this.